# Store reference to a file on disk in a browser's localstorage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

It seems with the current File API, the only way to access a previously added file is to store the entire File Object in local-storage. This can quickly eat away at the browsers memory when multiple files are added.

I was wondering if there is a way to only store some type of reference to the file in local-storage and be able to access that file with its reference.

I tried using the `URL.createObjectURL` function to generate a URL for the file but that URL is tied to the document and expires when the page is reloaded. Does any alternative exist?

Comment: I would like to believe that won't be possible cause otherwise that would cause s security risk, allowing a hostile website permanent access to a local file path, even if the contents change.

Comment: @Amit At least on linux files have `ctime` which is an unfakeable attribute that can be used to determine if a file has changed in any way. It could be used to implement persistent access with no less security issues than the temporary file references already have because the browser can easily determine if the file has changed in any way ever since the application first got the reference to it.

Comment: @tab1293 problem seems to be that there seems to be little interest for this feature (after hours of googling I only find like 2-3 people needing it), please voice your interest here https://github.com/w3c/FileAPI/issues/27

Comment: @Esailija - even if that makes some sense, web technologies aim to be as universal as possible so that can't be the responsibility of the API. An implementation can choose to implement this type of mechanism as an optimization though but I can't imagine anybody prioritizing such a feature

Answer (score -1):

By "quickly eat away at the browser's memory", I'm assuming you mean that your quota for LocalStorage is being used up by the files you're storing there. The local storage quotas are there to prevent websites from using up too much of a user's local disk space. By default, most browsers limit the storage to 5MB per domain.

[From the w3 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/#disk-space), the local storage quota is actually a feature to prevent what you're asking from happening (i.e. a website storing more files on a user's disk than the user has allowed quota for):

> User agents should limit the total amount of space allowed for storage areas, because hostile authors could otherwise use this feature to exhaust the user's available disk space.
>
> User agents should guard against sites storing data under their origin's other affiliated sites, e.g. storing up to the limit in a1.example.com, a2.example.com, a3.example.com, etc, circumventing the main example.com storage limit.
>
> User agents may prompt the user when quotas are reached, allowing the user to grant a site more space. This enables sites to store many user-created documents on the user's computer, for instance.

Comment: The file data actually isn't stored in local storage, it's stored in IndexedDB which can utilize up to 50% of the users hard drive. I am using localforage to locally store the file objects. But even with that additional space, the file is being duplicated and taking up uneccesary room on the users disk.